# Uses of ruthenium-106?

Tags: energy, radioactivity, nuclear

I read a news article recently about a cloud of ruthenium-106 being released over Europe. The article mentioned one of the uses for this specific isotope is in fuel cells for satellites. I tried to do some research but i couldn't find information on a fuel cell that used this specific isotope. What kinds of fuel cell or power generator use ruthenium-106?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator

Comment: @Mithoron for Ritegs alfa-emiters are usually used. Beta-emitters are usually used in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device

Answer (score 3):

Expanding @Mithoron's comment into an answer, $\ce{^{106}Ru}$ is used in [radioisotope thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) that power satellites. Plutonium-238, curium-244 and strontium-90 are the most often cited candidate isotopes for this purpose but other isotopes such as polonium-210, promethium-147, caesium-137, cerium-144, cobalt-60, curium-242, americium-241 and thulium isotopes have also been studied.

Apart from being an energy source, it also finds its application in medicine. $\ce{^{106}Ru}$ is used in cancer radiation therapy, especially to treat eye and skin tumors.